# Does Passenger support Rails v3 + Ruby v1.9.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

We are developing a new rails application and are considering moving to Rails 3. We have the following questions:

Does Passenger support Rails v3 + Ruby v1.9.2?

Does Rails v3 provide a significant performance improvement over Rails v2.3.8?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the latest Passenger 2.x versions supports Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2
Be sure to install one of the latest versions or you might encounter some incompatibilities.

Rails 3 provides several new features, a brand new architecture and some significant improvements on many Rails aspects, including performances on some specific topics. However, [some features](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5098-rails-3-beta-4-activerecord-5x-slower-than-rails-235) (such as `ActiveRecord#find`) are a little bit slower than Rails 2. The Rails core team is working on that.